# Exit DFS Recursion When Target Vertex Is Found And Return Path

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, search, depth-first-search

I have made a recursive DFS algorithm which can return a path when a target is found. Notice that I'm taking advantage of recursion and I try to utilize as less memory as possible in path saving. When the target is found, it is guaranteed that `path` will contain the correct path. But then the DFS must completely stop or else I cannot return a correct list due to the `pop()`s after. Temporary solution is a global list `result`. Is there any way to:

1. Stop the recursion after finding the target ?
2. Return the `path` list exactly at the specified point ?

```py
result = []

def dfs(graph, vertex, visited, path):

    global result
    if vertex not in visited:
        visited.add(vertex)
        if isTarget(vertex):
            print("Solution found ! " + str(path))
            result = path.copy() # recursion must stop here and return path at this state
        for neighbor in graph.getSuccessors(vertex):
            path.append(neighbor[1]) #neighbor[1] is direction 
            print("Visiting node" + str(neighbor[0]))
            dfs(graph, neighbor[0], visited, path)
            path.pop()
```

Comment: Have you tried putting `else` before last `for`?

Comment: @testing_22 Yes, didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I think, `dfs()` can return a list, which would allow us to continue/break the recursion. Something like:

```py
result = []

def dfs(graph, vertex, visited, path):

    if vertex not in visited:
        visited.add(vertex)
        if isTarget(vertex):
            print("Solution found ! " + str(path))
            return path # recursion stops here and returns path at this state
        for neighbor in graph.getSuccessors(vertex):
            path.append(neighbor[1]) #neighbor[1] is direction 
            print("Visiting node" + str(neighbor[0]))
            temp_path = dfs(graph, neighbor[0], visited, path)
            if temp_path:
                return temp_path # break recursion since path found
            path.pop()
    return [] # if no path/target node found

result = dfs()
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend separating the search logic from the traversal logic. This allows you to write `dfs` in a generic way and reuse it to traverse your graph for any graph-related operations -

```py
def dfs(graph, vertex, path = tuple(), visited = set()):
  if vertex in visited: return
  yield (vertex, path)
  for [v,dir] in graph.getSucessors(vertex):
    yield from dfs(graph, v, (*path, dir), {*visited, v})
```

Now `find` is just one of the many functions we may write around `dfs` -

```py
def find(graph, start, target):
  for (v, path) in dfs(graph, start):
    if v == target:
      return (v, path)
  return (None, None)
```

`dfs` is lazy and so iteration will stop as soon as `find` returns. Here's an example of how you might use it -

```py
(vertex, path) = find(graph, startVertex, targetVertex)
if not vertex:
  print("target not found")
else:
  print(f"found {vertex} at path {path}")
```

An advantage of this approach is the ability to find not just the first target, but *all* targets -

```py
def find_all(graph, start, target):
  return list((v, path) for (v, path) in dfs(graph, start) if v == target)
```

If you share `graph.getSuccessors`, I'm sure we could optimise that as well. If you write it to be lazy like `dfs`, both generators could benefit from early exit behaviour.

Comment: I liked that approach also, +1

Comment: I forgot to mention that a paused generator can be resumed, making it super easy to write things like `find_all`. See the edit for details :D